# understanding transition function by ALEX MACCAW

Tags: javascript

hey guys i am new to js and i was reading this article provided as a referance in bootstrap.js for transitions :

[CSS transitions using Jquery](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions)

now if you go to the part which says Programmatic transitions, thats the part that i tried implementing .

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bko4ohqL/).

but somehow the code from this famious article does't work .

Why ?

code below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var defaults = {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: ''
    };

    $.fn.transition = function (properties, options) {
        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        properties['webkitTransition'] = 'all ' + options.duration + 'ms ' + options.easing;
        console.log(properties);
        $(this).css(properties);
    };

    $('.element').transition({
        background: 'red'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in [transition.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/transition.js#L36)

i need to have some code like below :

```
var transEndEventNames = {
  WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
  MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
  OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
  transition       : 'transitionend'
}

for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
  if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
    return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
  }
}
```

my code was only working in chrome , while i was testing in mozilla .

Thanks for your time guys .